# Polyomino equation

Tags: tiling, polyomino

[image: On the left is a U pentomino. On the right is an I tromino.]

There is a particular shape (holes are permitted) that you can build with three copies of the piece on the left, or with 5 copies of the piece on the right.  You may rotate and flip the pieces, but they cannot overlap.  What shape can you build?

---

<sub>This puzzle is from: http://skepticsplay.blogspot.com/2010/04/polyomino-equations.html</sub>

Comment: Is the shape allowed to have a hole inside of it?

Comment: @Alaiko Yes, holes inside the shape are allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the following would be OK since holes are allowed in the shape.

> [image: Full_shape]
>  Using the piece on the left, 
>  [image: Piece_5] 
>  Using the piece on the right, 
>  [image: Piece_3]